# Blazor State Management - Factor out the state preservation to a common location

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-state-management

[image]

I'm trying to understand common location for state preservation from [Blazor Official Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#handle-prerendering).

- Should wrapping code be defined in separate razor component?
- How that component would refer `currentCount` variable?

[image]

I have tried to define this into new component like above in my project, but variable is undefined.

> How `Counter.razor` and `CounterStateProvider.razor` will be
> associated together?

[image]

Comment: I notice that the variable in the initialized block is begins with lowercase "c" while the property begins with uppercase "C". Is this just an issue with a case mismatch?

Comment: As @EricKing pointed out, was just a typo on docs. Fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/pull/22492/files  I vote to close question as 'was a typo'.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @daniherrera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize comments to help some on in future.

> `CurrentCount` is the property in defined in above class.